# Manage Stock only option available is Yes

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.2.6, stock, manage-stock

When I go to advanced inventory and want to set Manage Stock to No I only have the option Yes available. But why?
[image]

I have no idea where to start debugging any clue would be appreciated or maybe someone faced the same problem?

I already checked **Stroes > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory** settings and they look fine.

I don't know if it's related but how I found this bug was because a product I just created is apparently not salable and not listed in `cataloginventory_stock_status` table.

**Update:**
I figured out a bit more. The same problem affects **Qty Uses Decimals** too. In *Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select::setOptions* the following options are set for the selects **Manage Stock**, **Qty Uses Decimals** and **Allow Multiple Boxes for Shipping**:
[image]

`this.options`is set to the result of `parseOptions()` which gets `data` passed. In two of the cases the value `0` for label `"No"` is passed as integer and once as string. That's why `parseOptions()` will set the label to `' '`.

The label is `' '` but the source code for the select then is `<option data-title value="0"></option>` can anyone explain this or has an idea why?
Does anyone know where the data for the options is passed to the select ui component?

Comment: Is it fresh M2 installation?

Comment: No it is an already existing project. I checked it with an fresh install and there it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was completely on our side. We applied [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/18885/commits/5e7ac45672db8d937031bf5069da5d0204c72b11) core patch due to another [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18823) we had. Problem with this patch is the simple compare `==`. With a type compare `===` it works just fine again.

But I would be happy if someone could answer or update this answer to explain why sometimes the values are passed as strings and sometimes as integers.